# Getting the results depending on the present date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table that is similar the one below. My goal is to only return the results which are the upcoming dates, not the only which were already past.

```
id    |   date
1       Mar 12 2012 
2       Apr 17 2013
3       Oct 22 2014
4       Jul 12 2015
```

Desire result:

```
id    |   date
1       Oct 22 2014
2       Jul 12 2015
```

I have tried doing the line below, but it is returning zero results.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOW() < `date`

OR

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` > CURDATE() ;
```

Comment: Is your "date" column declared as a date value?  My guess is "No" - maybe you declared it as a string?  If you declared your column as one of these, your syntax should work: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Since the date contained string, I had to declare it as a string. Is there any problem about it?

Comment: Don't deface your post with some other question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, being a bit straight, your data is a mess :)

Basically, you can't store dates in MySQL using that format. That results in the column being a (var)char. Trying to sort a string as if it was a datetime will not only bring you trouble (which it has actually started because you had to post a question here) but will also result in poor query performance.

You should absolutely reconsider changing that into a `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

The function definition for CURDATE() returns a string of numbers: depending on context you'll either get '2008-06-13' or '20080613'. This can't be compared with 'Oct 22 2014' except as a string-- and I somehow don't think a string comparison is what you were shooting for.

If you can change the format of your 'date' field to be more like machine-readable dates (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html) on MYSQL date and time), you'd probably be able to have the compare work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function to compare string date.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%M %d %Y") > CURDATE() ;
```

Comment: it is still giving me zero results

Comment: Citing the documentation you linked: `Where date is a valid date and format specifies the output format for the date/time.`. Emphasis: `Where date is a valid date`

Answer (score 0):

This is right query for your desired result. now check your datatype for date column in database it should be date or datetime.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `date` > CURDATE( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use STR_TO_DATE function to convert string to date and compare

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%b %d %Y' )  > CURDATE( )
```